# phpgraphlib_v2.31 - Graph not loading into a Div in PHP

Tags: php, phpgraphlib

I used this link to create a graph in php.The graph created successfully.

But when i loading this into a div ,it displays error.

That means this is my code:

```
<div>
<?php
include('phpgraphlib.php');
$graph = new PHPGraphLib(500,350);
$data = array(12124, 5535, 43373, 22223, 90432, 23332, 15544, 24523,
 32778, 38878, 28787, 33243, 34832, 32302);
$graph->addData($data);
$graph->setTitle('Widgets Produced');
$graph->setGradient('red', 'maroon');
$graph->createGraph();
?>
</div>
```

Then it displys the error:

```
Image corrupt or truncated: http://localhost/graph/graph.php
```

What is the reason for that?

But when i deleted `<div>` and `</div>` tags ,then it displays the graphs perfectly.

But i need to display this in a div.

How can i do this?

How can i solve this?

Comment: I've googled for it and the major reason seems to be browser misinterpretation..Or a mime type mismatch

Comment: Check [this](http://boardreader.com/thread/Image_corrupt_or_truncated_after_PHP_re_5ft4kX3qpt7.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can not put any HTML or blank space prior to including phpgraphlib.php because of the header being sent withing the file.

Remove the dives and try this in another page:

```
<div>
<img src='GraphFile.php' />
</div>
```

Or Read This:
http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/documentation/tutorial-phpgraphlibpie-extension